# Change include path of static library

Tags: c++, cmake, static-libraries, include-path

I want to make a static library from a project of mine such that I can use it like this in other projects:

```
#include <MonoEngine/engine.hpp>
```

However right now I have a src folder in between:

```
#include <MonoEngine/src/engine.hpp>
```

How can I build the static library with CMake such that I can omit the `src/`?

This is roughly how my library folder is structured.

```
monoEngine
|-src
| |-engine.hpp
| |-engine.cpp
| |-subfolder1
|   |-file.hpp
|   |-file.cpp
|-CMakeLists.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create subfolder `include` and place all your headers in there and add that folder to your include path:

```
monoEngine
|-include
| |-MonoEngine
| | |-engine.hpp 
| | |-subfolder1
| |   |-public.hpp
|-src
| |-engine.cpp
| |-subfolder1
|   |-private.hpp (will not be shared with third parties)
|   |-file.cpp
|-CMakeLists.txt
```

That way headers in the `include` will provide the public interface of your library, while headers in the `src`-directory will not be exposed to third parties using your library. That's the common approach if build a library.

**Addendum:**

Since you asked in the comments below how to use this with CMake, a simple CMakeLists.txt could look like this (untested):

```
project( your_project )
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.0 )

set( SRC_LIST 
    include/MonoEngine/engine.hpp
    include/MonoEngine/subfolder1/public.hpp
    src/engine.cpp
    src/subfolder1/file.cpp
    src/subfolder1/private.h )

add_library( your_lib ${SRC_LIST} )
target_include_directories( your_lib PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src )

# and then optional parameters:
# target_compile_options( your_lib ... )
# target_link_libraries( your_lib ... )
# install(TARGETS your_lib ... )
```

Comment: Can you explain what I have to add to my CMakeLists.txt? Before I only had `add_definitions( -I${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src )`

Comment: I have added an example project file for CMake to my answer above.

Comment: I'm still having troubles when using ExternalProject, I will open a different question though, since it gets out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

cmake has a include_directories command which allows you to add directories to the list the compiler will look into for include files more details in the [documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html)

one you modify the build system you should be able to just write `#include <engine.hpp>` in your source code.

Comment: That's not what I want however. I still want the user to put my library name at the beginning of the include.